# Twitter API and Retweets

Tags: api, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API method 'getRetweets' to pull retweets of a specific status ID.
The problem I have is that the API only pulls back the new style 'automatic' RTs made using the specific RT button. I need to also pull back old style 'manual' retweets made by placeing the letters 'RT' in front of a tweet.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? At present the only thing I can think of is to use the search method, but that seems like overkill somehow.

Answer (score 0):

*Retweets* are always *mentions*. You could `GET statuses/mentions` of an authenticated user or just plain old `GET search` for '@his_username' 
In both cases you must manually map originals with the retweeted ones.

Comment: In my experimentation, offical RTs that use Twitter RT method, don't show up using statuses/mentions. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here, but they don't appear in my results. 
Nevertheless, I think mentions is the way to go over search - I'll just have to compare them to the original tweet.

Comment: I've also found that the search method is next to useless! It returns User IDs that are completely different from those used throughout the rest of twitter, and there's simply no way to map those returned by the search function to the actual ID of the user. The only way around this seems to be to do a user lookup for each returned result, using the screen name only.
Twitter acknowledged this as an issue several years ago but have yet to fix it.